# how can i pass soap object to one viewcontroller to another view controller in Swift-3

Tags: ios, soap

I am able to get response from SOAP and can also print in current viewController but i want to pass this response to secondViewController. I have tried the simple pass method but its not working.

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    print(mutableData)
    let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: mutableData as Data)
    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
    xmlParser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
    xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
    xmlParser.parse()
}

// Operation to do when a new element is parsed
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {


    lastElementName = currentElementName
    currentElementName = elementName as NSString

    if(elementName == firstNodeName){

        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        operation = NSMutableString()
        operation = ""
        message = NSMutableString()
        message = ""
        status = NSMutableString()
        status = ""
    }
}
// Operations to do for each element

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    //  print(String(format : "foundCharacters / value %@", string))
    if currentElementName == "message" {
        message.append(string)
        print(message) //I can print this response in my current ViewController But i cant pass this response to my secondViewController 

    }
    if currentElementName == "status" {
        status.append(string)
        print(status)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code how you open second view controller?

Comment: `if (segue.identifier == "secongView")  { let DestViewController : osecondViewController = segue.destination as! secondViewController . DestViewController.messageLabelText = message as String }`

Answer (score 0):

```
let responce = NSString(data: mutableData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Try converting your mutable data into NSString and then pass data as a String to another UIViewController.

Comment: //Ok, But i am already using for get data :                                                   (let xmlData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            self.xmlData = NSMutableData(data: data!))