# How to pass soap response to next viewController in swift3

Tags: ios, soap

I am working on swift3 with SOAP. I received response from soap but i can not send this response to my secondView Controller

```
Body: <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-
ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:doRegisterUserResponse 
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><response><status 
xsi:type="xsd:string">successful</status></response>
</ns1:doRegisterUserResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-
ENV:Envelope>>.value
Response = successful
```

I tried to pass with

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

if (segue.identifier == "secondView")
    {

        let  DestViewController1:secondViewController = segue.destination as! secondViewController
        DestViewController1.responseText = self.value(forKey: status as String) as! String!

    }
}
```

Please help Thankyou

Comment: Use custom delegates

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you "can not send this response"
 - cannot compile the code
 - crash on execution
 - everything appears to work, but nothing is updated?

As a small point to aid clarity, you should not use capitalised variable names - `DestViewController1` should only be used to define a class or struct, and `destViewController1` would be a better variable name - and `secondViewController` should be `SecondViewController`

- Do you have a variable `responseText` in the second controller?
- where are you holding the SOAP response? `self.value()` doesn't seem to make much sense.  Do you mean self.responseText.value()`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i mean to say that i have received response "Success"  from server and i store it in `status` so i want to pass that response to my secondViewController , yes i have variable `responseText` `func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
  
        if currentElementName == "status" {
            status.append(string)
            print(status)
            
        }
    }`

Comment: please See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977491/how-can-i-pass-soap-object-to-one-viewcontroller-to-another-view-controller-in-s]